# Marriage tax in the Rhineland under Prussian rule

Tags: 19th-century, germany, marriage-practices, prussia, rhineland-palatinate

I am searching for marriage taxes or fees that had to be paid in 19th century Rhineland under Prussian rule.

Comment: Are you looking for information about them, or records of who paid them? Could you explain in the question a little more about what they were, if you know.

Comment: http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/2796/104 might be helpful.

Comment: Without more information about what you're looking for, it's hard to make a stab at answering this, which is why it's gathering votes to "close" (i.e. put it on hold until it's clarified).

Comment: As an aside, I've come to the conclusion that this is very difficult to research on the 'net unless you speak German (which I don't). I'm relatively certain that there are few if any relevant tax records online; most of the promising leads I've found by googling are in academic papers behind paywalls. I suspect the tax in question is the fee for a marriage licence, which seems to have been higher for some groups (e.g. Jews and possibly Mennonites) than others.

Comment: I can't imagine the user actually expects to find tax records form the 1800s in Prussia. It should be safe to assume that they're looking for information on laws and policies.

Comment: Though I don't know how that could be beneficial to family history.

Comment: @JustinY, I can find tax records (e.g. land tax, window tax, stamp duties, death duties) in England and Wales from the 1800s, so why shouldn't they be available for other locations? Some of the England and Wales records are even online.

Comment: Certainly these kinds of records are available in German archives. It doesn't seem too important to me that these archives are not (as a rule) digitized. Once you know where to look, you can certainly find many such records.

Comment: @GeneGolovchinsky, I thought such records for Germany would be available, even if simply in archives. I'd argue that digitization is important for researchers who are in a different country or not able to travel but I suspect tax records are a long way down the priority list for those who do the digitisation.

Comment: I agree that these records aren't easy to get at! But they are valuable for all sorts of information, and may be worth the price of paying someone local to find them

Answer (score 5):

Some marriage register records will have official stamps in them documenting that a fee was paid, and how much it was. I expect these fees varied from place to place and over time. Furthermore, different documents associated with a marriage might also have different fees. Below is an example of two such stamps (on two different pages) from an 1822 marriage in Gauersheim, a village near Kirchheimbolanden in the Pfalz.

[image]